# d3.js line chart draw left to right animation only new data add

Tags: d3.js, overlay, marker

**Q1.**
I wanna make a streaming area chart using **D3.js v4**.

now I'm update chart data when get data using Ajax every sec.

```
var path = svg.append("g")
    .attr("clip-path", "url(#clip)")
    .append("path")
    .datum(data)
    .attr("class", "line")
    .attr("d", line)
    .style("stroke-width", 1)
    .style("stroke", "white")
    .style("fill", "none");
tick();

function tick() {
    apiData.splice(0, 1);
    data.push(apiData[0])
    var newLength = path.node().getTotalLength();
    path.attr("d", line)
        .attr("class", "line")
        .attr("transform", null)
        .attr("stroke-dasharray", totalLength + " " + totalLength)
        .attr("stroke-dashoffset", totalLength)
        .transition()
        .duration(2000)
        .attr("stroke-dashoffset", 0)
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + x(-1) + ",0)")
        .on("end", tick);
}
```

I want to animate just new data added without legacy data.

But this code work(drawing animation) working with all data.

**Q2.** I wanna make a glow point like this video.

I think this step will be work for me,

step 1. make a div

```
<div id="glow-point"></div>
```

step 2. css absolute position.

```
<style>
#glow-point {
    position: absolute;
    background-color: rgb(0, 150, 0);
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 40px 12px rgb(0, 120, 0);
    width: 5px;
    height: 5px;
    left: -1;
    top: -1;
    border-radius: 50px;
    animation: pulse 1s infinite;
}
</style>
```

step 3. when svg ondraw, get x,y points.

```
var glowPoint = document.getElementById('glow-point');
glowPoint.style.left = ????
glowPoint.style.top = ????
```

But i don't know how can i get x,y points when **d3.js** svg drawing. T.T

anybody help?

Here's reference Video. [reference Video.](http://bigfile.mail.naver.com/bigfileupload/download?fid=6PFcbrwl14m9KqtwHqujKqvmHqUmKx2wKouwKAv9KAuXHqu9FAbwKqUqaxvjMovrMqICax+vKAM9KqgwFqk0KquqFAUqpAI0M4tqaxt=)

Here's [my fiddler](http://jsfiddle.net/qAHC2/1956/)

please help me..... i can't solve it...

Comment: anybody help...?? T.T